# Higher kinded type and Tagless final

Tags: scala, tagless-final

I'm trying to write a function that can take any tagless final trait and return `F[String]`.

```
def apply[Api[F[_]]](implementation: Api[F[_]]): F[String] = ???
```

I don't understand why the above is not compiling.

The following works.

```
trait Api[F[_]]

def apply[F[_]](implementation: Api[F[_]]): F[String] = ???
```

But how can I get rid of this trait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
def apply[Api[_[_]], F[_]](implementation: Api[F]): F[String] = ???
```

When you write `apply[Api[F[_]]](..)` you don't declare `Api` and `F`, you declare only `Api`. There `F` doesn't matter, you can write `apply[Api[F[_]]](..)` or `apply[Api[G[_]]](..)` or just `apply[Api[_[_]]](..)`, anyway you can't use `F` outside.

`Api[F[_]]` is correct syntax in declaration of type parameter, in type application in type position you should write `Api[F]`.